# Editing php for dropdown menu

Tags: php

I'd like to edit my dropdown menu so it goes straight from bars to actual menu.

```
$item_output = $args->before;

    /*
     * Glyphicons
     * ===========
     * Since the the menu item is NOT a Divider or Header we check the see
     * if there is a value in the attr_title property. If the attr_title
     * property is NOT null we apply it as the class name for the glyphicon.
     */
    if ( ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ) {
        $item_output .= '<a' . $attributes . '><span class="glyphicon ' . esc_attr( $item->attr_title ) . '"></span>&nbsp;';
    } else {
        $item_output .= '<a' . $attributes . '>';
    }

    $item_output .= $args->link_before . apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID ) . $args->link_after;
    $item_output .= ( $args->has_children ) ? ' </a><span class="dropdown-toggle shapely-dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>' : '</a>';
    $item_output .= $args->after;

    $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );
}// End if().
}
```

Html

```
                    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
                </div>

                <div class="module-group right">    
                    <div class="module left">


                        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse"><ul id="menu" class="menu"><li id="menu-item-3530" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-3530 dropdown"><a title="Contact" href="https://4309.co.uk/contact/">Contact </a><span class="dropdown-toggle shapely-dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
```

If CSS can be used, great, but I'm wondering of php might not be the only solution.

[here](https://4309.co.uk)

Comment: What do you mean by `straight from bars to actual menu`? Linear interpolation effect (animation)? Edit: nvm your "here" link example seems to be updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove the element:

```
<span class="dropdown-toggle shapely-dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
```

and then you can go and add a CSS rule to `.dropdown-menu` class for the `ul`:

```
display: block !important;
```

[image]

Comment: @newnew having it checked in my browser with a little tinkering from Inspector, it seems to be working. You can try it and let me know of the result.

Comment: And do i remove the`'` surrounding it too?

Comment: So removed ver vatim `</a><span class="dropdown-toggle shapely-dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>` without the `'` and its dropping from `fa bars` to a small blank white space. Now let me try next step....

Comment: So if i write `.dropdown-menu ul {display: block;}` that's good?

Comment: Just write `.dropdown-menu { display: block !important;}`. `.dropdown-menu ul` is capturing a `ul` child of element with `dropdown-menu` class, not the element with `dropdown-menu` class.

Comment: Ok tried it and still have blank white space where menu was...?

Comment: Refresh your page, I can see it.

Comment: Refreshed, checked mobile which I'm using and responsive desktop checker. Nothing on both. Just blank white space....

Comment: @newnew I updated my answer with what I see in my browser, based on the link you provided in your question.

Comment: Yeah, thanks so much, and i think you're on the right lines. Just strange that i can't see the menu and you can. Have you checked mobile?...

Comment: Because there are two menu functions. One for desktop one for mobile. Could that be a cause reason etc...?

Comment: @newnew a screenshot would be helpful. The reason you do not see it in mobile is because you placed the CSS rule to be applied for displays with width greater than 992 pixels. I cannot see it in mobile either.

Comment: Ah, so if i ad `@media {max-width: 768px}{.dropdown-menu {display: block ! important;}`

Comment: Now i see it. I can't see it in desktop but I'll have a fiddle and see... Thanks so much.

Comment: @newnew you're welcome, you should add that rule to be global, outside of media queries.

Comment: I added it to my style.css. Correct?

Comment: I'll add it as global and higher media query in my additional css so that hopefully i can get it to work in desktop too.